# PHP Include/Require Relative path from WebRoot Issues

Tags: php

I've done a ton of programming in many languages but newer to hardcore PHP.  After tons of googling i can't seem to find a good solultion to include/require/require_once using a relative path from webroot rather than relative path from OS.

I adjusted the PHP Ini include path which was a great solution but the problem is that many PHP IDE's don't evaluate the Include Path in order to expose Class definitions for intellisense etc... So i find myself having to make many temporary includes while debugging/coding.

Classic ASP and other languages to me made this so much easier with relative pathing always being relative from web root rather than php's relative of current file location and php's root being root of the file system.  I have seen tons of quirky weird methods to try to work around this but that is exactly what it always seems to be a work around.

Can any of you help make my week and solve this tedius irritating challenge for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always add something like this to your `php.ini` file:

```
ROOT_PATH = "/var/www/<your_directory>"
```

Then you could pick up this value in your php page like:

```
$ROOT_PATH = ini_get("ROOT_PATH");
```

And then you could include files like this:

```
include_once($ROOT_PATH."/<path>/<filename.php>");
```

Of course you could simply add `define("ROOT_PATH", "/var/www/<your_directory>");` directly in the file, but if you get the settings from the `php.ini` you could have different settings on different servers.

Comment: This is a solid answer... i just think the problem is my IDE isn't smart enough to crawl.  I'm trying to have a master include that actually includes core class files etc... and this just doesn't work in the IDE but it works fine via the web server.  I have a ton of OOP going on so i need the intellisense on the classes to make it easier, but thank you for the answer... appreciate it.